# inner .par collection breaks outer ForkJoinTaskSupport in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to make a parallel collection that uses a fixed number of threads. 
 The standard advice for this is to set tasksupport for the parallel collection to use a ForkJoinTaskSupport with a ForkJoinPool with a fixed number of threads.  That works fine UNTIL the processing you are doing in your parallel collection itself uses a parallel collection.  When this is the case it appears that the limit set for the ForkJoinPool goes away.

A simple test looks something like the following:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool
import scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport

object InnerPar {

  def forkJoinPoolIsSuccess(useInnerPar:Boolean): Boolean = {
    val numTasks = 100
    val numThreads = 10

    // every thread in the outer collection will increment
    // and decrement this counter as it starts and exits
    val threadCounter = new AtomicInteger(0)

    // function that returns the thread count when we first
    // started running and creates an inner parallel collection
    def incrementAndCountThreads(idx:Int):Int = {
      val otherThreadsRunning:Int = threadCounter.getAndAdd(1)
      if (useInnerPar) {
        (0 until 20).toSeq.par.map { elem => elem + 1 }
      }
      Thread.sleep(10)
      threadCounter.getAndAdd(-1)
      otherThreadsRunning + 1
    }

    // create parallel collection using a ForkJoinPool with numThreads
    val parCollection = (0 until numTasks).toVector.par
    parCollection.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(numThreads))
    val threadCountLogList = parCollection.map { idx =>
      incrementAndCountThreads(idx)
    }

    // the total number of threads running should not have exceeded
    // numThreads at any point, similarly we hope that the number of
    // simultaneously executing threads was close numThreads at some point
    val respectsNumThreadsCapSuccess = threadCountLogList.max <= numThreads

    respectsNumThreadsCapSuccess
  } 


  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    val testConfigs = Seq(true, false, true, false)
    testConfigs.foreach { useInnerPar =>
      val isSuccess =  forkJoinPoolIsSuccess(useInnerPar)
      println(f"useInnerPar $useInnerPar%6s, success is $isSuccess%6s") 
    }
  }
}
```

And from this we get the following output, showing that more than numThreads (in the example 10) threads are running simultaneously if we create a parallel collection inside of incrementAndCountThreads().

```
useInnerPar   true, success is  false
useInnerPar  false, success is   true
useInnerPar   true, success is  false
useInnerPar  false, success is   true
```

Also note that using a ForkJoinTaskSupport in the inner collection does not fix the problem.  In other words you get the same results if you use the following code for the inner collection:

```
  if (useInnerPar) {
    val innerParCollection = (0 until 20).toVector.par
    innerParCollection.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(3))
    innerParCollection.map { elem => elem + 1 }
  }
```

I'm using Scala 2.12.5 and Java OpenJDK 1.8.0_161-b14 on a Linux 3.10.0 x86_64 kernel.

Am I missing something?  If not is there a way to work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you should provide same task support  for internal parallel collection too.

Comment: The problem still appears if you explicitly set taskSupport in the inner collection.  I have updated my original post.

Comment: I run it locally and got `true` on my machine for all cases.

Comment: That's interesting.  What OS / Scala / Java versions are you using?  I edited my post again to describe the environment where I'm seeing this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Mac OS / JDK 8 / Scala 2.12.6

Comment: here its all true too: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GttsO4R3QVWmGuGCq9qZMQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue is that in Java 8 the numThreads parameter passed to the ForkJoinPool is just a guide, not a hard limit.  In Java 9 there is a maxPoolSize parameter you can set which should provide a hard limit for the number of threads in the pool and solve this problem directly.  I don't know of a great way to solve this in Java 8.

See the following for more details:
https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11036